# How can I separate two separated words in a variable?

Tags: python

I have a variable that contains two words separated by a space, and I want to split it into two variables, one for each word. How would I do this?

As an example, my string would be `hello there` and I want to split it into the variables `word1` and `word2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = 'hello there'

word1, word2 = s.split()
```

will do this for you. E.g.,

```
In [63]: s = 'hello there'
In [64]: word1, word2 = s.split()
In [65]: print word1
hello
In [66]: print word2
there
```

`split()` is quite versatile, you can also specify other characters to split on. For more information on `split()` see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split):

```
s = "hello world"
word1, word2 = s.split(' ', 1)
```

It splits a string into a list by the char you provide as an argument. Default is a space, but I'm using it as a parameter just to make it clearer.

You can also provide the `maxsplit` argument and make sure the string gets splitted no more than `maxsplit` times (like in our string - we must have exatly one split, because we're inserting the splitted words into excatly two variables.).

Answer (score 1):

```
word1, word2 = 'hello there'.split()
```